# Needing to share a static mutable map among corda nodes

Tags: corda

Good day,

I've been trying to change the messaging layer for the corda framework from AMQP to FTL. I've tried doing so by creating a map where I associate an InboxSubscriber object to a particular p2p address. The p2p address, which is just a string, can be retrieved from the parameter target: MessageRecipients. I've added a static MutableMap in the ArtemisMessagingServer class and added a corresponding InboxSubscriber object, keyed by the p2p Address of the server that is being initialized. I had hoped that this map would be one for all of the corda nodes, but I've noticed that in fact I have a map for each node, thus I'm unable to get the corresponding InboxSubscriber objects for other nodes other than itself. Is there a particular location where this map could be created and then retrieved by all the nodes in the network?

[image: Changes in ArtemisMessagingServer.kt]
[image: Changes in the NodeMessagingClient.kt]

Answer (score 0):

For this information to be shared, you need to create a Corda service. This service would then be hosted on the node, and you could request information from it as part of a flow.

For an example of a node offering a service, see the Oracle Example [here](https://github.com/corda/samples). In the `build.gradle` file, we list `NodeB` as offering the `net.corda.examples.primes_oracle` service.

We then define the service [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/oracle-example/service/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/oracle/service/service/Oracle.kt), and the handler flows for querying the node offering the service [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V3/oracle-example/service/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/oracle/service/flow).

Essentially, the service will be a long-lived object on `NodeB`. When other nodes query it, it extracts information from this object and sends it back to the other nodes as part of a flow.